# application pool recyclying

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I've a web application running on windows server 2008 x64. Application use cache to save some data but while working this data disappeared. it seams that the application pool recycles.

I disabled the application pool recycling (no over lapping recycle, privet memory limit is zero also the virtual memory is zero and no interval limits specified ).

after these configurations application pool recycles!

is there any default windows configuration that limits the application pools worker process?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting any errors that crash the pool?

Comment: after enabling logging nothing written in event log, unhandled exceptions causes all application pool to crash or only the app domain?

Comment: Some exceptions may crash the pool, but i think that no all of them do. What's the reset interval you see?

Comment: 5 minutes fixed interval, and no other condition to reset?

Comment: No other conditions all disabled

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16502/discussion-between-hadad-and-carlos-grappa)